# Manhwa where the female lead has two brothers and is allergic (?) to black flowers

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I read this manhwa long time ago, but I forgot the title and want to read it again. What I remember from the manhwa is:

The female lead (FL) has two brothers and her father doesn't like her. The FL is allergic(?) to a black flower (I don't know the flower's name); the flower is like a poison to her. Her brothers give the FL the black colored flower to apologize, because they've been neglecting her, but the FL starts to cough blood after receiving it.

The FL's brothers' hair color, from what I remember, are black (first brother) and blond or silver/white (second brother). I don't really remember the FL's hair color, but I think it's either blonde or silver/white.

From what I remember, I think the story involved either isekai or reincarnation.

Please help me find this manhwa.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What colour is the female lead's hair? Also, are there any science fiction or fantasy elements to this manhwa?

Comment: I think its historical manhwa, I don't really remember the fl hair but I think its either blonde or silver/white @LogicDictates

Comment: Is there anything magical or supernatural in the manhwa? Did it involve isekai (transportation to another world) or reincarnation, for example? If there's nothing sci-fi or fantasy about it, then this question is off-topic here.

Comment: From what I remember I think its either isekai or reincarnation @LogicDictates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *[The Taming of the Tyrant](https://tapas.io/series/the-taming-of-the-tyrant/info)*, aka *I Tamed a Tyrant and Ran Away*.

> All Charlize Ronan ever wanted was to bring honor to her family. But instead, she is forced into becoming a “living sword” -- a mere tool for the emperors. It is from this hell that she prays for justice… and awakens in her former body. Now, determined to tear down this horrible empire, Charlize seeks out the young prince, Dylan Blade. She will put him on the throne, not as an honorable ruler, but as a tyrant. It is time for Charlize to tame the one who will bring forth her revenge.

The scene with the flowers is chapter 32, with the ending of chapter 30 showing the planned gift of black flowers, but not providing an explanation. She is one of the rare people with a specific magical allergy to those flowers. The brothers weren't aware of this, but the father was, and he suggested the gift.

[image: Charlize, coughing from the flowers: "Do you wish to kill me?"]